# Use UpdateCursor to update a field based on text in other field

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I am trying to find the correct syntax for the UpdateCursor where I look for part of a text from another field.  I have many values of PCD zoning codes (PCD 03, PCD 04, PCD 05, etc).  I want to calculate my "ZONING_DESC" field based off these PCD values in my "ZONING" field where all PCD values get calculated to "Planned Commercial Development".  I know that '==' operator is finding exact values.  Is there an operator for finding like values?

Here is my Code:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(Zoning, ["ZONING", "ZONING_DESC"]) as cursor:
    if row[0] == 'PCD%':
        row[1] = 'Planned Commercial Development'
    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Answer (score 3):

In place of the SQL wildcard `%`, use the Python string method `startswith` as below.

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(Zoning, ["ZONING", "ZONING_DESC"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0].startswith('PCD'):
            row[1] = 'Planned Commercial Development'
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Thanks @BERA, didn't notice that wasn't in the code snippet. Edited answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply trying to test if the ZONING field starts with PCD, then you can just write a python expression to test if the 3 left most characters equal PCD.  That would look something like:

```
if row[0][:3] == 'PCD':
```

You may want to check out documentation on String Slices (such as at https://developers.google.com/edu/python/strings)